Is there any built-in way in Flask/Jinja to create a link with the URL?
An example, in CommonMark, if I type:
http://example.com

Then this will get converted to:
<a href="http://example.com">http://example.com</a>

This tag has 2x the http://example.com as strictly necessary - one for presentation as the body of the <a> tag, and one as the href.
In Jinja/Flask this can be accomplished with:
<a href="{{ url_for('something') }}">{{ url_for('something') }}</a>

which works, but I can't help but to feel like there should be a better way. I suppose I could do something like write my own function and inject that into the Jinja context so I could do something like:
a(url_for('example.page'), _self=True)

Is there a better way?

In HTML, that has exactly as many appearances of the URL as needed, given you want both the text content and href attribute of the element to contain the URL.

The best I have is app.jinja_env.globals.update() but it'll be cumbersome to have it called via jinja and then display - more so than what you have. I don't think there's too much wrong with your example

I've had a good go at trying to think this out and I can't think of a way you can skip it. Returning the full <a...> string from the backend is probably awful

Rather then injecting an external python function into jinja2 you can simply define a jinja2 macro to render the link for you.
{% macro render_link(url) %}
    <a href="{{ url }}">{{ url }}</a>
{% endmacro %}

Then import the macro into the templates where you intend to use it and call it with.
{{ render_link(url_for('something')) }}

